# Firebase messaging is not supported in your browser how to solve this?

Tags: reactjs, push-notification

I am using firebase messaging for web push notification with react. But browser show this message

> Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)

This is code :

```
const initializedFirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXX"
});

if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    let messaging = initializedFirebaseApp.messaging();
}
```

`firebase.messaging.isSupported()` is always returning the false. Is there any way I should proceed?

Version for react : 16.8.2 and firebase version : 6.0.2

Comment: What browser / OS are you working on?

Comment: Chrome version 74 using and Windows OS using

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. it is occurring in localhost and also firebase hosted(HTTP)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

FCM supports only in **localhost and the https** enabled sites only. if you want FCM to support you need to either work on localhost or deploy somewhere (you can use firebase).

If you are using proxy using nginx like local.somehost.com cloud messaging doesn't support. To solve this you need to make your local.somehost.com as HTTPS you can install openssl and certificate and key in your nginx.

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: i hosting with Firebase but still occur same error in android webview

Comment: I get this error on localhost as well. In my case, localhost is within an Android WebView. The app was built with Capacitor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the above explanation you can check if the browser supports messaging by doing:

`const messaging = firebase.messaging.isSupported() ? firebase.messaging() : null`

Comment: This solution worked for me. Firefox incognito not supported firebase.

Comment: @barış çıracı your comment solved my issue. Private browsing even in Google Chrome has this problem. I tried on normal window (not private browsing / incognito) and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

**isSupported() in version 9**
*return Promise* so you should wait for resolving

```
const messaging = (async () => {
try {
    const isSupportedBrowser = await isSupported();
    if (isSupportedBrowser) {
        return getMessaging(config);
    }
    console.log('Firebase not supported this browser');
    return null;
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
}
})();
```

**If you are using *version 9* you should pass *messaging* to (onMessageListener resolver and getToken )**

> onMessageListener

```
export const onMessageListener = async () =>
new Promise((resolve) =>
    (async () => {
        const messagingResolve = await messaging;
        onMessage(messagingResolve, (payload) => {
            // console.log('On message: ', messaging, payload);
            resolve(payload);
        });
    })()
);
```

> getToken

```
export const requestForToken = async (dispatch) => {
try {
    const messagingResolve = await messaging;
    const currentToken = await getToken(messagingResolve, {
        vapidKey: *your FCM APP SERVER KEY*,
    });
    if (currentToken) {
        *your code*
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I used dynamic imports for solving this issue so that the file is not even evaluated before the feature is detected. I am using firebase SDK 8.2.0.
This is how my useEffect function looks like on the top level of my app.

```
import { isSupported } from "firebase/messaging";

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const hasFirebaseMessagingSupport = await isSupported();
    if (hasFirebaseMessagingSupport) {
      const { requestForToken } = await import("./api/cloud-notification/firebase");
      await requestForToken();
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

This is how my firebase connection file looks like ("./api/cloud-notification/firebase"):

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

const FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY = "your-firebase-public-vapid-key";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = getMessaging();

const getFirebaseToken = async () => {
  try {
    const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: FIREBASE_VAPID_KEY });
    if (!currentToken) {
      console.log("No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", error);
  }
};

export const requestForToken = async () => {
  try {
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
    if (permission === "granted") {
      await getFirebaseToken();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("An error occurred while getting user permission. ", error);
  }
};
```