# Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting this error after deploying our website , my domain is domain.com and i can't change it to https or localhost , so how do i get rid of this error.

```
provider.ts:122 Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
    at e.instanceFactory (index.ts:56:25)
    at e.getOrInitializeService (provider.ts:318:33)
    at e.getImmediate (provider.ts:115:21)
    at e._getService (firebaseApp.ts:136:22)
    at e.<computed> [as messaging] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:228:29)
    at Object.s [as messaging] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:209:32)
    at Module.<anonymous> (firebaseInit.js:18:28)
    at a ((index):1:2329)
    at r ((index):1:2198)
    at Array.t [as push] ((index):1:2061)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is only supported on HTTPS web sites. If you can't put your site on HTTPS, you won't be able to use FCM to deliver push notifications.

Also see:

- [Firebase messaging is not supported in your browser how to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215286/firebase-messaging-is-not-supported-in-your-browser-how-to-solve-this)

Comment: Is this true for localhost? Is there any way to test FCM in development?

Comment: I'm getting this error on localhost for Safari but not Chrome. I'm also interested to know how to deal with localhost...

Comment: You can use a tunnel cloudflare or ngrok could do the job