# Nextjs I can't integrate firebase cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting this error  `unhandledRejection: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).`

Here is my configurations:

**firebase_config/config.js**

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  .....
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Initialize Firebase Cloud Messaging and get a reference to the service
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

export default app;
```

**pages/firebase.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    import app from "../firebase_config/firebase_config";
    const firebase = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Firebase</h1>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default firebase;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Firebase messaging is not supported in your browser how to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215286/firebase-messaging-is-not-supported-in-your-browser-how-to-solve-this)?

Comment: @juliomalves no. Before posting the question I treid it and didn't work

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this problem?